# Plotting numerous timeseries on top of each other using ggplot assistance

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data as follows:

```
 Key  Date                     y   x1   x2   x3
   1    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   3    2    5
   1    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   5    7    2
   1    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    5   7    4    7 
   1    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   2    7    6
   2    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   6    3    8
   2    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   7    7    3
   2    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   2    3    4
   2    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   6    2    7
```

I am trying to use this code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(date,`x1`,`x2`)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y",ncol=1)
```

But am getting an error:

```
Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, vars, drop = params$drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you get the error because you don't have a variable called `variable`. My guess is you need to use `tidyr::gather` to put your data into long format

Comment: What do you intend to be represented by x1 and x2? `aes` generally expects named arguments past the first two, which are assumed to be x and y values, so I'm not sure what you would be mapping x2 onto